# Analogy between 2 CPU having same Instruction Set Architecture (ISA)

Tags: cpu-architecture

We have 2 CPU which has this properties-

1. Clock Rate
2. CPI
3. Execution time
4. No of instructions
5. MIPS, will always be identical?

If 2 machines have the same Instruction Set Architecture, which of the upper mentioned property will be same?

Comment: Is it No, as far as I understand, 4 and 1?

Comment: You need to show what you think. Your train of thought and ask a specific question about what you think you are misunderstanding. Just dumping this kind of homework/exam question will not be received well.

Comment: @bolov: In hindsight I agree, I somewhat regret answering; I was going to just comment with a trivial answer, but it was basically a full answer so I posted it as such.  The OP did at least take a guess, but yeah that's barely better than just dumping the assignment / practice problem when it's a multiple choice like this.  But OTOH, even `4` isn't necessarily true so that's worth saying something about.  Still not a good SO question, but I decided to leave my answer up because it's at least mildly interesting to possible future readers - it's not super-specific like most homework is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 will be true (same dynamic instruction count) unless the program has speed-dependent behaviour (e.g. keep looping checking the time until 0.1 seconds have elapsed, or other more interesting examples you could come up with).

No reason for `1` to be true, and it's very easy to find counter-examples if you go to any online computer store and look at different models of the same generation of x86-64 CPUs with different max clock speeds.  And across different generations, there can be even larger differences in clock speed, e.g. a 25MHz 80386 vs. a 5GHz Zen 2 or Coffee Lake.